# How to configure multiple address endpoints to a single endpoint

Tags: wso2, endpoint, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Am working with  *wso2esb 4.7.0* and *wso2dss 3.0.0*.

I have diffident number of data services in my DSS

so, when we are creating a proxy service in my ESB, generally will send the payload to the respective address endpoint of the particular data service in the DSS  and will execute the proxy

But what i want to do is create an Endpoint  in ESB  and configure all my DSS Address endpoints in this Endpoint and use this in all my proxy services

some of my Address endpoints in DSS are as shown below

```
localhost:9764/services/Get_details/

localhost:9764/services/Get_geodetails/

localhost:9764/services/muser_DataService/
```

how can i create a default endpoint with this Address endpoints in my ESB

Comment: Your question is not very clear for me. Do you want a single proxy to invoke your DSS endpoints depending on the payload or do you want the same payload to be sent to all DSS endpoints? The latter might not make sense, but I'm just trying to understand the scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the replay @isuru perera,I want to send my proxy payload to one of the dss endpoint point not to all of them,Is there any way that i can configure my payload to go to a particular Address endpoint in the group of endpoints,I hope u got my point....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single proxy in ESB and call different DSS endpoints based on the message contents. Please go through the [mediators](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Mediators) under Filter category.

For your scenario, you may use the [Switch Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Switch+Mediator). From that, you can check for different conditions and send to appropriate endpoint.

For eg: please refer [Content-Based Router Pattern](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Content-Based+Router)

You may use a mediator like [Payload Factory](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator) to transform message depending on the target endpoint.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Isuru Perera plz look in to the below link and help me if u have any solution for this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478909/wso2esb-authentication-service-exception